# Plugin Python depends on unknown plugins org.jetbrains.plugins.yaml, org.jetbrains.plugins.remote-run, Coverage

Tags: python, plugins, intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

I'm using IDEA CE 13.1.1 and tried to install the Python plugin version 3.4.Beta.135.1 from file because my development PC has no access to internet for security reasons. But get following warning and the plugin get not activated:

Plugin Python depends on unknown plugins org.jetbrains.plugins.yaml, org.jetbrains.plugins.remote-run, Coverage

I searched for these plugins in the repository but did not find them, only references in other plugin details that depend on them.

How are they really called? How can I find them?
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, for the Intellij IDEA Community Edition there is a Python Community Edition plugin.

Here is the link http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7322?pr=idea_ce

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Python plugin with Idea Community edition, sorry. It  requires IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

Comment: I see, just noticed there is a Python and a Python Community Edition plugins. I'll try with the second one and let you know. Thanks!